# Sequelize Ошибка Error: read ECONNRESET при запросе в БД

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

PostgreSQL 9.6.2
Запросы шлю с приложения node.js + sequelize

В документации к [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#findall-search-for-multiple-elements-in-the-database) есть примеры составления запросов, в данном случае findAll

Пробую пример

```
console.log('user id: ', req.decoded);
    db.orders.findAll({where: {userId: req.decoded.id}})
        .then(function (orders) {
            console.log('orders from db: ', orders);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('orders request error from db: ', err);
        });
console.log('end of function');
```

Лог консоли

```
user id:  { id: 2 }
end of function
orders request error from db:  { SequelizeConnectionError: read ECONNRESET
    at D:\NodeJSProjects\ParkingHouse\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\connection-manager.js:110:20
    at Connection.<anonymous> (D:\NodeJSProjects\ParkingHouse\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:186:5)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\NodeJSProjects\ParkingHouse\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:86:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1278:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
  name: 'SequelizeConnectionError',
  message: 'read ECONNRESET',
  parent: 
   { Error: read ECONNRESET
       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
       at TCP.onread (net.js:569:26) code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' },
  original: 
   { Error: read ECONNRESET
       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
       at TCP.onread (net.js:569:26) code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' } }
```

спустя какое то время повторяется запрос и уже тогда получаю данные и БД.

1. почему сервер бд обрывает соединение?
2. запрос надо обворачивать в промис что бы дожидаться ответа?

Comment: А нет у этой БД подобной опции, как у MongoDB - socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1 } ? Не, это ж не ответ, я чиста для интересу предполагаю - может, она есть, и её надо только указать при подключении.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в антивируснике F-Secure, поставил другой, все работает.
https://community.f-secure.com/t5/Business/DeepGuard-seems-to-cause/td-p/88447
http://holdemmanager.nlclub.org/faq/339.html#F-Secure